# Beep sound while starting Windows 7 Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, lenovo-laptop

While starting my Windows 7 Lenova Laptop, a beep sound occurs. If I press arrow buttons continuously, sometimes the laptop starts normally.

How to solve the problem? Is it a hardware problem?

Comment: Yes, probably a hardware issue. Here's a list of Lenovo POST beep codes. http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht035729

Answer (score 0):

Just visit the link, and associate the bip code with your current bip:

http://support.lenovo.com/en/documents/ht035729

Reference about Beep Codes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test#Progress_and_error_reporting